# Running materialized view refresh in parallel

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, data-warehouse

I have a large materialized view that is refreshed periodically (complete refresh) and I would like to do it in parallel. I can already run the query part in parallel but the problem is (much slower) delete in the beginning of refresh.

I have done the following:

- set the table and query degree to 6
- alter session enable parallel dml;
- run refresh with option "parallelism => 6"

But delete still runs serially. Is there some option I have missed?

Answer (score 1):

Set *atomic_refresh* to *false*. It will truncate your MV table instead of deleting records.